# How to bypass "Try it / Install" screen when booting from USB Live Session? (without installing in the USB)

Tags: live-usb

This has been asked several times already (I found it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32484), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7429) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15470)), but basically everyone simply recommend to perform a full install to the USB stick. But I do need it to stay as a LIVE session, not a "full install on USB", for a number of reasons (the most important one being that using Live session I can easily install Ubuntu using the desktop icon)

So, my constraints for skipping the Welcome Screen (and automatically choose "Try Ubuntu" option) are:

- It must actually be the Ubuntu Live session (or as close to the default as possible). Same software selection (gparted is present in live sessions, gimp is not, for example), user (name and ID), behavior (no login screen, no password for `sudo`, to name a few), no GRUB, etc. That rules out an Ubuntu full install on USB.
- It must be able to install Ubuntu in the computer (while full install requires the ISO file, an additional USB stick, and the hassle of Startup Disk Creator)
- If possible, to be as fast as the "text-based launcher" (the one you have when you press a key right after the kernel loads)
- It must be completely automatic, unattended from boot to desktop.
- Select a different language than default. It can be a hard-corded selection (actually, it must, since boot itself shall be fully unattended). But preferably be easily changed ("easily" as in editing a config file then rebooting)

**Is it possible?**

The proposed (great) solutions that I've ruled out so far are:

- Installing Ubuntu in the USB stick *(for all of the above mentioned reasons)*
- Remove `Ubiquity` package *(it removes the ability to install the system from that USB as well)*
- Ubuntu Customization Kit (ubk): *several [limitations and caveats](https://answers.launchpad.net/uck/+faq/1093), and its not even in the repos*
- Remastersys / LiLi: *its the same as full direct USB install, only customized.*

An ideal solution would be something like "create USB sick using Startup Disk Creator, then open it and remove / edit / add file(s) xxx, yyy, zzz"

Comment: I replaced the code on my USB that I had in syslinux.cfg with what was suggested, but I still get the prompt. (Original lines: vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
ui gfxboot bootlogo) Is it possible that I should do something with the txt.cfg (below): label persist
menu label ^Persistent Mode kernel /casper/vmlinuz append bootkbd=us console-setup/layoutcode=en_US console-setup/variantcode=nodeadkeys locale=us_us persistent noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz splash --
label live menu label ^Live Mode kernel /casper/vmlinuz append

Answer (score 42, accepted):

*This guide was made for Ubuntu (Gnome). It works for Kubuntu (KDE) too, with a few exceptions*

I've been able to get the Live CD boot straight into a Live session without timeout or fancy menu, optionally with a language pack installed.

### Live USB (16.04)

1. Mount the USB with Ubuntu installed in it
2. Backup the file `syslinux/syslinux.cfg`. We will modify it so we need
   to replace it back if something goes wrong.
3. Open the following files under syslinux directory: `syslinux.cfg` and
   `txt.cfg`
4. Delete (or comment) everything in `syslinux.cfg`.
5. The `txt.cfg` file has the default GRUB menu entries. Copy the live
   one to `syslinux.cfg`:

   ```
   default live
   label live
   menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
   kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
   append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent noprompt floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0 ignore_uuid initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
   ```
6. You can add any specific kernel parameters needed for your device in
   the append line.
7. Save isolinux.cfg and boot your system using the USB. It will boot
   straight to the desktop now.

### Live USB (13.10)

1. Mount the USB with Ubuntu installed in it
2. Backup the file `isolinux/isolinux.cfg`. We will modify it so we need
   to replace it back if something goes wrong.
3. Open the following files under isolinux directory: `isolinux.cfg` and
   `txt.cfg`
4. Delete everything in `isolinux.cfg`.
5. The `txt.cfg` file has the default GRUB menu entries. Copy the live
   one to `isolinux.cfg`:

   ```
   default live
   label live
   menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
   kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
   append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent noprompt floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0 ignore_uuid initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
   ```
6. You can add any specific kernel parameters needed for your device in
   the append line.
7. Save isolinux.cfg and boot your system using the USB. It will boot
   straight to the desktop now.

[[source](http://oldpapyrus.wordpress.com/tag/ubuntu-usb-skip-bypass-try-install-screen/)]

### Live USB (11.04)

1. Go to the root folder of your Live USB
2. Enter the `syslinux` directory
3. Make the `syslinux.cfg` file writeable
4. Replace the contents of the file `syslinux.cfg` with:

   ```
   default live
   label live
     say Booting an Ubuntu Live session...
     kernel /casper/vmlinuz
     append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt --
   ```
5. Optional: localize the system (see below)

### Live CD

1. If you've a Live CD in your CD drive, mount it. Otherwise, if you've an ISO file available, mount it on `/media/cdrom` by running the next command in a [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) (replace the name of the `.iso` file accordingly):

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop,ro ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso /media/cdrom
   ```
2. Create a temporary directory in which the CD contents can be stored, say `~/live-cd` (`mkdir ~/live-cd`)
3. Copy the contents of the CD to the folder `~/live-cd/iso` (`cp -r /media/cdrom ~/live-cd/iso`)
4. Since the Live CD is not needed anymore, it can be unmounted (`sudo umount /media/cdrom`)
5. Open the `~/live-cd/iso` folder (`cd ~/live-cd/iso`)
6. Enter the `isolinux` directory (`cd isolinux`)
7. Make the `isolinux.cfg` file writable (`chmod u+w isolinux.cfg`)
8. Replace the contents of the file `isolinux.cfg` with:

   ```
   default live
   label live
     say Booting an Ubuntu Live session...
     kernel /casper/vmlinuz
     append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
   ```
9. Optional: localize the system (see below)
10. [Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and run:

    ```
    cd ~/live-cd
    chmod u+w iso/isolinux/isolinux.bin
    mkisofs -r -V "Ubuntu Live session" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o ubuntu-11.04-live-amd64.iso iso
    ```
11. The new iso will be available at `~/live-cd/ubuntu-11.04-live-amd64.iso`. To save space, the `~/live-cd/iso` directory can be removed. (`rm -rf ~/live-cd/iso`)
12. Now burn the `ubuntu-11.04-live-amd64.iso` file on a CD if needed.

### Localize Ubuntu (translations)

If you want the system in the languages English, Spanish, Portuguese, Xhosa or Simplified Chinese, you've just to add the `locale=` boot option with `en`, `es`, `pt`, `xh` or `zh` to the `append` line as in:

```
... quiet splash locale=pt --
```

Otherwise, if you do not want to modify the file containing the root file system (`filesystem.squashfs`) and do not mind hacking around, continue reading.

Open a terminal and navigate to the `~/live-cd/iso` directory and put the code from http://pastebin.com/VTdt9WFZ in a file (name it `install-locale`) and run it.

This script mounts the `filesystem.squashfs`, retrieves version information of the language packs from it, downloads the packages and put those in the directory `locale-hack`. Next, a script is created that installs the language packages on boot time. To make that work, the script also modifies the `syslinux.cfg` or `isolinux.cfg` file to apply these changes.

You'll be asked for a locale, enter something like `nl` or `de`. The script is not that clever to understand things like `Dutch` or `German`. Afterwards, the file can be removed

The terminal commands that should be executed:

```
cd ~/live-cd/iso
wget http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VTdt9WFZ -O install-locale
bash install-locale
rm install-locale
```

Note that adding language pack can cause the generated `.iso` file to be bigger than 700MB which won't fit on a CD. For virtual machines however, it suffices. This hack has as a side-effect that Plymouth does not work (i.e. you do not get a fancy boot screen), but at least the system is translated when logging in. Otherwise, you had to install `language-pack-gnome-*` manually.

### References

- [Syslinux example](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/SYSLINUX#How_do_I_Configure_SYSLINUX.3F)
- [Ubuntu Help on custominizing a disk / burning it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization#Burning%20the%20CD)

Comment: +1 for that! It worked! (using the Live USB method). I will also consider adding `noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true` to the `append` line, since thats the way it is in `txt.cfg`. Do you know what these additional parameters do? Also, can the solution be improved to include the language?

Comment: `noprompt` shuts the system down without asking for removing the CD. I've added that to the Live USB line because it does not make sense with USB media. I don't know what `cdrom-detect/try-usb=true` does. All language packs are not included by default on the Live CD because of its size. To set a different locale (e.g. NL), pass the `locale=nl_NL` option on the `append` line. This will set the **locale** but not the language for Gnome because the package is simply unavailable on the Live CD.

Comment: @MestreLion: updated with a hack for a localized environment.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: the packages are avaliable on the Live CD, because when you select a different language, Ubuntu starts Live session in that language. Ill try your suggestion about `locale=pt_BR`. Maybe thats all thats needed.

Comment: @MestreLion: not really, I've tested it with both `locale=nl` and the language selection menu at Try/Install. In both cases, I got an English layout although the `locale` command outputs `nl_NL.UTF-8`.

Comment: nl_NL = Neaderlands entry in the menu, right? Well, maybe *that* entry has no associated language pack. But try "Portugues do Brasil", it does boot a Brazilian Live Session. Anyway, Ill accept your answer, since i guess this is the closest we will get.  Is there any chat / irc / IM that we can talk further?

Comment: Chat @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: Is it at all possible that the Live USB change would break persistence? I distinctly remember turning on persistence when I "burned" the image to my USB stick, and it definitely isn't remembering my changes across reboots.

Comment: @MichaelMS It shouldn't break persistence as the modification causes the CD straight boot in a Live session. Try adding the `persistence` argument to the `append` line: `append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistence initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt --` (taken from [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent#Making_the_drive_bootable))

Comment: @Lekensteyn I switched the config file back to the original, and persistence worked, so I'm inclined to think this answer doesn't work well with persistence in its current form.  I'll be sure to try adding the `persistence` argument when I get home later today, thanks!

Comment: Because I just failed to add persistence: The argument is called `persistent`, not persisten**ce**. The rest still works very well!

Comment: What about Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? Does the 13.10 'recipe' work?

Comment: 13.10 recipe working on 16.04 and 15.10!

Comment: I have tried this on 20.4 LTS and it does not work ( I could apply both Live USB 16.4 and 13.10)

Comment: Looking for 20.04 Focal Fossa solution...

Answer (score 1):

The above works great for both Startup Disk Creator and UNetbootin installs.
If you are using a persistent flash drive you will want to add the word persistent thus:

```
default live
label live
  say Booting an Ubuntu Live session...
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt --
```

For a 64 bit system the code is a little different

```
default live
label live
  say Booting an Ubuntu Live session...
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt --
```

Comment: Is this any different from Lekensteyn's answer combined with his comment from Jun 20 '11 at 8:08?

Comment: Not sure, where can I find his comment from Jun 20 '11 at 8:08?

Comment: It's the third-from-last comment in his answer above

Comment: The original answer has been edited since my post, Lekensteyn's original answer did not mention "persistent" or the ".efi" required for 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

In 14.04 and perhaps earlier, Ubiquity uses upstart to start. You can disable this by modifying `/etc/init/ubiquity.conf`.

1) If you are not using the Live install itself, first mount casper-rw:

```
# Mount the usb_drive manually if nautilus has not done it for you
# Change sdb1 to the proper location of your usb drive, find it using sudo blkid
sudo mkdir /media/$USER/usb_drive
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/$USER/usb_drive
# Create a mount point for the read-write file system and mount via loopback
sudo mkdir /media/$USER/casper-rw
sudo mount -o loop /media/$USER/usb_drive/casper_rw /media/$USER/casper-rw
cd /media/$USER/casper-rw
```

2) Edit `etc/init/ubiquity.conf` within the Live install and comment out the following lines:

```
#start on (starting gdm
#          or starting kdm
#          or starting xdm
#          or starting lxdm
#          or starting lightdm)
```

If you are remastering the disk, you could just edit the master `ubiquity.conf` in the squashfs system. Ubiquity will then be completely out of your way upon restart.

3) Unmount the drives

```
sudo umount /media/$USER/*
```

Comment: I have tried this on 20.04.1 LTS live and this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Any reason u didnt want remastersys?
You could install the os, make an iso with remastersys
extract the squashfs file and replace the one on the stock iso, (or premade usb folder)

I do this often

Comment: Using remastersys I would end up with a full install, not a live session. Read my 1st constraint: It must actually be the Ubuntu Live session (or as close to the default as possible). Same software selection (gparted is present in live sessions, gimp is not, for example), user (name and ID), behavior (no login screen, no password for sudo, to name a few), no GRUB, etc. That rules out an Ubuntu full install on USB.