# Can I write to a live USB stick?

Tags: usb, mount, live-usb, read-only

I'm trying to create a Live USB stick with additional files on it.
I created my live USB using Startup Disc Creator and I've tried to remount /cdrom directory [as it described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54613/can-i-write-to-the-usb-stick-that-im-running-ubuntu-from) but it answers

```
mount: cannot remount rw read-write, is write-protected
```

I even tried to write to the stick while I'm booted from my hdd, but with the same result:

```
fgh@fgh-box:/media/fgh$ sudo mount -o remount, rw /media/fgh/Ubuntu\ 16.04.1\ LTS\ amd64/
mount: cannot remount rw read-write, is write-protected
```

I also tried

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdc
```

doesn't work.

I would be grateful if you help me with making it writable.

Comment: I wrote an answer here that shows you how to set up persistence to allow you to save to a Live USB.  http://askubuntu.com/a/842844/231142

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would be the differences between a persistent USB Live Session and a installed Ubuntu in a USB drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **mkusb** to build your stick, it will create a persistent partition with the size you specify and use the remaining space for a NTFS partition that can be used by Linux and Windows.