# How to remove the "install ubuntu" splash from a live usb

Tags: live-usb

I want to use usb sticks for teaching a programming class, so I don't want the "install ubuntu" option splash at the start, is there a way to edit a start-up file to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but check this link out:
http://geekyprojects.com/ubuntu/build-your-own-custom-ubuntu-livecd/

It treats the subject of creating a custom Ubuntu LiveCD from an Ubuntu distribution.

Otherwise, I imagine there should be some possibility to edit the menu.v32 file(s) inside the Ubuntu ISO, I do not know of such tools though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using Ubuntu's **Startup Disk Creator** which displays a splash screen with two options: (1) TRY UBUNTU (2) INSTALL UBUNTU

However, if you install and use [MultiSystem](http://liveusb.info/) to create Ubuntu live USB from ISO image file, you won't get this splash screen, and **go straight to desktop**.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread:

[How to bypass "Try it / Install" screen when booting from USB Live Session? (without installing in the USB)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit)

For 32bit and 64bit **persistent** installs see my answer on that page.