# Is my Dell Inspiron n5050 laptop compatible with Xubuntu 12.10 ?

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, live-usb

Xubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64 doesn't boot in live usb mode. Only the boot screen appears and then it stops.

My laptop is already running Ubuntu 12.04, and since Xubuntu 12.10 live USB boot only shows the boot logo, can Xubuntu be incompatible with my Dell Inspiron n5050 laptop ?

```
Hardware overview
Processor
Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B940 @ 2.00GHz
Video
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
Network
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Network
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
Video
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
```

Comment: Please have a look at this question/answer here on Ask Ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/q/47522/8698

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201105-8079/ looks like it's certified, even.