# Want to get rid of installer on Ubuntu for flash drive

Tags: live-usb

I'm wondering if it's possible for me to get rid of the pop-ups on my screen asking if I want to install Ubuntu. (I'm using a USB drive) And so I can basically carry around a flash drive to be used as a computer.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-wold-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-install and also http://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit

Comment: I think the best move would be to just install Ubuntu onto a flash drive from another bootable flash drive as it the second, the target of the the installation were an ordinary hard drive. Of course, there may be problems with hardware-specific settings. I have a 32GB flash drive here. I'll try it and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be sufficient to uninstall `ubiquity`, but I'm not sure. You can try it and if it doesn't work, just reinstall it. :)