# Live USB stopped working

Tags: installation, boot, partitioning, live-usb

I had 13.04 32bit running great on a Sandisk Extreme USB 3.0 64gb stick.

For the most part I use it on a Toshiba Portege laptop but sometimes on various desktops as well.

I set the usb drive up with unetbootin, I split the drive into roughly two 30gb partitions following this thread  http://www.howtogeek.com/97177/how-to-put-ubuntu-linux-on-a-usb-thumb-drive-without-the-mess/ so that I could use it as a thumb-drive as well.

I also partitioned the Live install section following this thread https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent so that I would have a larger persistence drive.

I also bypassed the unetbootin install or run screen following this thread [How to bypass "Try it / Install" screen when booting from USB Live Session? (without installing in the USB)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit)

All of this worked great and I was a bit proud of myself as I am relatively new to Linux and well...  I had a nice USB thumb drive that worked great for standard file storage and swapping, plus a killer install of Ubuntu that ran VERY fast, loaded right up to the sign in desktop and functioned perfectly!

Then last night I tried to boot up the Toshiba laptop and I found myself staring at the purple loading screen with Ubuntu in the center and the little progress squares lighting up from once side to the other under it.  It hangs there indefinitely.  I've tried it on several systems and I get the same results.

Here the error message:

[image: Error Message]

I really do not want to start from scratch as I have the install customized the way I like, loaded with software I want and all set up to my tastes.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix the problem, or for that matter what the actual problem is?

Comment: type ESC and you should switch to a text screen, with error messages, which you can add to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added a link to a picture of the errors, see the post :-)

Answer (score 0):

looks like a damaged filesystem.  If you have a running linux, mount the persistent partition and fsck it.  If not, on a UEFI machine, you actually will run grub, and can edit the boot lines -- remove the word "persistent" on the linux line, boot, and you should have a clean live media boot, mount the partition which you used for persistence and fsck it.  If not a UEFI machine, if you can edit the /syslinux/text.cfg (Not sure of the name) file and find the linux boot line with the word "persistent" on it, remove the word persistent. Next boot should be a clean install media, mount other partition and fsck it.
  If the filesystem is clean, then I don't know what to suggest since you see the problem on multiple machines.  But you can backup the persistent partition, and restore it onto another live media's persistent partition.

Comment: Thanks for the effort ubfan1, in a bout of frustration I wiped the drive and started over around 3:00am last night :-)