# Unattended installation xubuntu

Tags: installation, xubuntu, ubiquity, preseed

I'm trying to setup an unattended install of Xubuntu 13.10.
It currently picks up all the settings but it still requires me to click next on each screen. I understand editing the xubuntu.seed isn't best practice however I'm just trying to get it to get working.

I have tried automatic-ubiquity and priority=critical but neither seems to make a difference; I have a feeling the install process is being called from somewhere else, bypassing these settings.

**txt.cfg**

```
default live-install
label live
  menu label ^Try Xubuntu without installing
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/xubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label live-install
  menu label ^Install Preseed Xubuntu 13.10
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/xubuntu.seed boot=casper languagechooser/language-name=English countrychooser/shortlist=NZ localechooser/supported-locales=en_US.UTF-8 automatic-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash priority=critical --
label check
  menu label ^Check disc for defects
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

**xubuntu.seed**

```
# Enable extras.ubuntu.com.
d-i apt-setup/extras boolean true
# Install the Xubuntu desktop.
tasksel/first multiselect xubuntu-desktop
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us    
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string NZ
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_NZ.UTF-8
d-i time/zone string Pacific/Auckland   
d-i mirror/http/mirror select nz.archive.ubuntu.com
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string Xubuntu-undefined
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i passwd/user-fullname string Administrator
d-i passwd/username string user
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password $1$D8xyolIs$nDCtVHsk5r0UeNyvVjK.D0
d-i passwd/auto-login boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
d-i preseed/late_command string echo 'x11vnc -usepw -forever' >> /etc/rc.local; chmod +x /etc/rc.local; apt-get install remmina, x11vnc
```

For safety, I haven't specified whether to automatically format sda until its ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this using a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit)

I took the params from my txt.cfg, backed up my syslinux.cfg file and replaced all the lines with the params.