# How to bypass “Try it / Install” screen when booting from USB Live Session of 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, grub2, live-usb

I'm trying to accomplish the exact same thing as MestreLion from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit). The answers given there were for 11.04 and 13.10 and are no longer workable for 14.04 LTS.

Basically I want a 14.04 LTS Live USB drive that boots directly to desktop. No grub screen, no login screen, and without any keyboard or mouse inputs.

Comment: Here is [user166879](http://askubuntu.com/users/166879/user166879)'s [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/483345/172634) to [MestreLion](http://askubuntu.com/users/11015/mestrelion) question how to do it in 14.04. I tried it and it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bypass "Try it / Install" screen when booting from USB Live Session? (without installing in the USB)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how to customize your live CD:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

a short version of the above:
http://nathanpfry.com/how-to-customize-an-ubuntu-installation-disc/

I suspect that if you use the stuff you linked to, looks like editing CFG files, then you will get to where you want to be.