# Custom live CD - Skip Install/boot to desktop and run a custom app

Tags: live-cd, .desktop, custom-distributions, syslinux

Following the list of instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) I was able to create a live CD that I can boot (testing in VirtualBox), but I can't seem to find a way to "boot to desktop", skipping the "Install dialog".

[image: Screenshot]

I have to wait until the Install app is loaded and then click *Try Ubuntu* to finally get to the desktop.

Essentially I want to boot to the desktop and also launch an application that I store somewhere in the filesystem. Can I somehow disable Install app from appearing and replace it with an application of my own choosing (that I already store somewhere on the filesystem)?

Comment: There is [a similar post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit) with various and longer explanations. However, this is for earlier releases i.e. 13.10, 11.04 and likely untested with newer releases.

Answer (score 2):

The SYSLINUX configuration on Ubuntu Live CD is somewhat confusing, but I had figured out by reading [this post on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32243/how-do-i-configure-syslinux-to-boot-immediately) and refer to [this Syslinux Wiki](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Config).

### Part A: Skip install/Boot to desktop

To boot directly to Live session, you need to do two things:

1. replace the `default vesamenu.c32` with `default live` (whose label `live` is found in `/isolinux/txt.cfg` file)
2. comment the last line `ui gfxboot bootlogo` using `#` at beginning of line

Step 2 is required, otherwise the initial splash screen will still be visible until timeout. This is due to `ui` module will override the `default` setting, as explained in [this subtopic on the Wiki](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Config#UI):

> Therefore, if UI is used, the PROMPT directive is ignored and the UI command -- not the DEFAULT command -- is automatically launched

**Default** `/isolinux/isolinux.cfg`

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
ui gfxboot bootlogo
```

**Modified** `/isolinux/isolinux.cfg`

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default live
prompt 0
timeout 50
#ui gfxboot bootlogo
```

I have tested the modified configuration using Xubuntu 14.04 ISO image, but the same steps should apply to other Ubuntu and official derivatives.

### Part B: Run custom app

As for launching the application, it should be doable by adding the path of target executable to the "startup" menu or something similar. For example, on Xfce Desktop Environment, it is found at **Settings Manager > Session and Startup > Application Autostart**.

Above all, my answer is more toward the solution for "Skip install/Boot to desktop". The latter part "Run custom app" shouldn't be an issue for most users.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20+

Remove the ubuntu ubiquity option from the command line.

So in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Remove `maybe-ubiquity` or `only-ubiquity` from the grub boot option. This will take you straight to the live desktop.