# Boot Live CD into 'Try Ubuntu' by default

Tags: 15.10, live-cd, customization, isolinux

I am creating a custom live CD based on Ubuntu 15.10. When the user sees the first boot screen (and doesn't press a key), it will automatically boot into a GUI menu where the user can choose 'Try Ubuntu' or 'Install Ubuntu':

[image: first boot screen image]

However, if the user presses a key, it gets a text menu. Selecting 'Try Ubuntu' boots directly into the desired live CD:

[image: text boot menu image]

I can successfully remove the installer boot entries in the text menu (`isolinux/txt.cfg`), but this doesn't change the default boot option when the user does not press any key. Removing the installation package `ubiquity` is not an option, I just want to prevent the user from starting the installer directly.

How can I change the default boot option to boot into 'Try Ubuntu'?

Comment: [This older post](http://askubuntu.com/q/47522/37165) had asked for Live USB but the top answer has covered Live CD with rebuilding the ISO image. For essential instructions only, I have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 5):

**This is the simplified and revised version of [this older answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/652834/37165).**

To boot directly to Live session, look for `/isolinux/isolinux.cfg` in the content of the ISO image file and modify these two lines of code:

1. Replace the `default vesamenu.c32` with `default live`
2. Comment the last line `ui gfxboot bootlogo` by inserting `#` at the beginning of line

Step 2 is required, otherwise the initial splash screen will still be visible until timeout. This is due to `ui` module will override the `default` setting, as explained on the Wiki (see "References").

### Default configuration

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
ui gfxboot bootlogo
```

### Modified configuration

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default live
prompt 0
timeout 50
#ui gfxboot bootlogo
```

I have tested the modified configuration using Xubuntu 14.04 ISO image. The same steps are likely applicable to any Ubuntu and official flavours, regardless of the release.

### References

1. [How do I configure syslinux to boot immediately](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32243/125388) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange
2. [Config](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Config) on Syslinux Wiki

Comment: Depending on whether you are using the regular desktop or alternate/server ISO and whether your computer is new enough to have UEFI and running in "Legacy" (CSR aka BIOS compatibility) or in UEFI mode you may also need to edit the `$ISO_PATH/boot/grub/grub.cfg` if to add `set default=0` or whatever entry you want it to boot.