# How to automatically choose install on the tryit/install screen from a USB Live Session of 16.04 LTS?

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to create a USB drive that will install Ubuntu 16.04 on a machine that boots from it. This install should be completely automated, so that I simply need to plug the USB drive in and turn the machine on (assuming it's set to try booting from the USB drive first).

I am currently using the Desktop image found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), because the machines I use this on will end up being used by someone as a desktop.

The current problem I am having is that when I start the machine it brings up the Try it/Install screen, which requires input before it will do anything. I have seen some questions on this site that tell you how to automatically bypass in favor of "Try it", but I need to automatically bypass in favor of "Install". My plan is to then use preseeding (see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html)) to ensure the installation is completely automated.

Is there a way to do this? Am I on the wrong track to getting a completely automated installation?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What you could do, if you can't get this to work, might be to use an imaging / disk cloning software like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). First install to one computer, and then clone the install to all the others.

Comment: [Here you go.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit) Google is your friend.